# Why SEQUENCE is used in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-sequence

I am brushing up my knowledge about SQL and I am learning more and more. However, I am not understanding the purpose of the Sequence we use. I am using SQL Server.

Comment: A sequence is used to generate unique numbers efficiently (e.g. for generated primary keys)

Answer (score 1):

The sequence object is an alternative, more flexible key-generating mechanism than
identity. Unlike identity, it’s not tied to a particular column in a particular table. Whenever you need to generate a new value, you invoke a function against the object and use the returned value wherever you like. It also supports specifying a minimum value and a maximum value, and cycling too.

Comment: Also note that sequences are ANSI/ISO SQL standard.